# How to replace the second occurrence of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the second occurrence of a string in javascript. I'm using a regex to detect all the matches of the character that I'm looking for. The alert returns the same initial text.

```
text = 'BLABLA';
//var count = (texte.match(/B/g) || []).length;
var t=0;   
texte.replace(/B/g, function (match) {
t++;
return (t === 2) ? "Z" : match;
});
alert(text);
```

https://js.do/code/157264

Comment: http://js.do/code/157301

Comment: `text` vs `texte`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's because you never use the result returned by the `replace` function.

Here's the corrected code:

```js
const text = 'BLABLA'
let t = 0
const result = text.replace(/B/g, match => ++t === 2 ? 'Z' : match)

console.log(result)
```