# How to replace the last match of regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
const spaceRegex = /<mspace\s+.*?\/>/
const answer = '<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>h</mi><mfenced><mi>x<mspace linebreak="newline"/></mi></mfenced><mo>=</mo><semantics><mrow><mo>-</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow></semantics><mspace linebreak="newline"/><mi>D</mi><mo>=</mo><mi mathvariant="normal">&#x211D;</mi></math>'
```

I have a regex to match `<mspace .... />`, there are two matches in the above answer.
I want to replace the last match with `<mspace width="10px"/>`

So I want the output to be,

```
'<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>h</mi><mfenced><mi>x<mspace linebreak="newline"/></mi></mfenced><mo>=</mo><semantics><mrow><mo>-</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow></semantics><mspace width="10px"/><mi>D</mi><mo>=</mo><mi mathvariant="normal">&#x211D;</mi></math>'
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you're using regex where it wasn't intended to be used; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/

Comment: [String.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) seems like it should do the job.

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568739/10905239
Reach me if you didnt understand it

Comment: Not a very elegant way, but you could do this `/<mspace\s+(?!.+?<mspace).*?\/>/`. This assumes that both occurrences exist in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not a right way to deal with XML.
The better one is using [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer) so you can traverse the DOM and update elements using DOM methods:

```js
const answer = '<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>h</mi><mfenced><mi>x<mspace linebreak="newline"/></mi></mfenced><mo>=</mo><semantics><mrow><mo>-</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow></semantics><mspace linebreak="newline"/><mi>D</mi><mo>=</mo><mi mathvariant="normal">&#x211D;</mi></math>';

const D = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(answer, "text/xml")

const mspaces = D.getElementsByTagName('mspace');
mspaces[mspaces.length-1].outerHTML = '<mspace width="10px"/>';

const updated = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(D);

console.log(updated)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0; max-height:none !important}
```

The regex solution is also available, but less reliable:

```js
const answer = '<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>h</mi><mfenced><mi>x<mspace linebreak="newline"/></mi></mfenced><mo>=</mo><semantics><mrow><mo>-</mo><mn>3</mn></mrow></semantics><mspace linebreak="newline"/><mi>D</mi><mo>=</mo><mi mathvariant="normal">&#x211D;</mi></math>';

const updated = answer.replace(/(.*)<mspace[^/]+\/>/, '$1<mspace width="10px"/>');

console.log(updated)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top:0; max-height:none !important}
```

Hope this helps.