# JSON string replace second instance skip first instance javascript / reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, string

I have a JSON string I am running a replace method on, I would like to replace the second instance of a sub string In the JSON string.
please see the string below.

I have two instances of this string `pw.alert.timestamp.iso` I would like to skip the first instance and replace the second instance.

```
{ "blocks": [{"type": "header","text": {"type": "plain_text","text": "{{pw.alert.severity}} - {{details}} - {{open_violations_count_critical}}"}} ], "attachments": [{"color": "{{pw.state.severityColor}}","blocks": [{"type": "section","text": {"type": "plain_text","text": "Triggered: {{pw.state.workflowId}}"}},{"type": "section","text": {"text": "Triggered:  {{metadata}}","type": "plain_text"}},{"type": "section","text": {"text": "Triggered: {{pw.alert.timestamp.iso}}","type": "plain_text"}},{"text": {"text": "{{pw.alert.description}}","type": "mrkdwn"},"type": "section"},{"type": "actions","elements": [{"url": "{{pw.alert.alertUrl}}","type": "button","value": "View Alert","action_id": "button-action-1","text": {"text": "View Alert","emoji": true,"type": "plain_text"}}]},{"text": {"type": "plain_text","text": "CORRELATIONS"},"type": "header"},{"text": {"text": "<{{pw.link.openall}} | *Open All*> | <{{pw.link.downloadall}} | *Download All*>","type": "mrkdwn"},"type": "section"},{"type": "header","text": {"type": "plain_text","emoji": true,"text": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.name}}"}},{"type": "divider"},{"text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.0.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.0.name}}*>"},"type": "section"},{"text": {"text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.1.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.1.name}}*>","type": "mrkdwn"},"type": "section"},{"text": {"text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.2.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.2.name}}*>","type": "mrkdwn"},"type": "section"},{"text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.3.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.3.name}}*>"},"type": "section"},{"type": "section","text": {"text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.4.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.4.name}}*>","type": "mrkdwn"}},{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.5.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.5.name}}*>"}},{"type": "header","text": {"type": "plain_text","emoji": true,"text": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.2.name}}"}},{"type": "divider"},{"text": {"text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.2.destination.0.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.2.destination.0.name}}*>","type": "mrkdwn"},"type": "section"},{"type": "header","text": {"text": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.3.name}}","emoji": true,"type": "plain_text"}},{"type": "divider"},{"type": "section","text": {"text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.3.destination.0.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.3.destination.0.name}}*>","type": "mrkdwn"}},{"text": {"text": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.name}}","emoji": true,"type": "plain_text"},"type": "header"},{"type": "divider"},{"text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.destination.0.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.destination.0.name}}*>"},"type": "section"},{"text": {"text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.destination.1.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.destination.1.name}}*>","type": "mrkdwn"},"type": "section"},{"text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.destination.2.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.destination.2.name}}*>"},"type": "section"},{"text": {"text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.destination.3.url}} | * {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.4.destination.3.name}}*>","type": "mrkdwn"},"type": "section"},{"text": {"type": "plain_text","text": ": camera: Snapshots","emoji": true},"type": "header"},{"type": "divider"},{"type": "section","text": {"text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.0.snapshot.protectedUrl}} | *High-Resolution Image: {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.0.name}}*>","type": "mrkdwn"}},{"title": {"emoji": true,"type": "plain_text","text": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.0.name}}"},"alt_text": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.0.name}}","image_url": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.0.snapshot.publicUrl}}","type": "image"},{"type": "section","text": {"type": "mrkdwn","text": "<{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.3.snapshot.protectedUrl}} | *High-Resolution Image: {{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.3.name}}*>"}},{"type": "image","alt_text": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.3.name}}","image_url": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.3.snapshot.publicUrl}}","title": {"emoji": true,"text": "{{pw.workflow.destinationGroup.1.destination.3.name}}","type": "plain_text"}}]} ]}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you're doing string operations on the JSON rather than JSON.parse, and then manipulating the JavaScript object and then JSON.stringify the changed object.

Comment: No, I am extracting the JSON from an Html div, which is editable, in some cases the user may want to copy a part of the JSON in the HTML div which is a mix of JSON and HTML. Some of the divs in the JSON can be removed on click, in cases where there is more than one div with the same text I would like to replace only the second instance. I am looking for a way maybe using regex and replace to start the replace from the second occurrence.

Comment: Try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44568739/1563833) also shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584748/find-and-replace-nth-occurrence-of-bracketed-expression-in-string).  Double duplicate answers for a double string replace! ;)

Comment: this worked for me, I had to reverse the matches, but it works really appreciate it thanks. ```  rawJson = rawJson.replaceAll(`\{\{${html.html}\}}`, match => ++i === 2 ? '' : `\{\{${html.html}\}}`) ``` @Wyck